# How to securely execute user provided Python code on Linux

Tags: python, linux, security, permissions

I have a pipeline where one step would be preprocessing data. Is there a way to let user input code for the process securely. Requirement would be no filesystem, network, exec access. Just run the code with zero side effects. Even better if there is something that kills it after 100ms if it get stuck. Imports could be static outside user input if it messes things up.

Example function that user supplies.

```
def parse(input: str) -> str:
    import re
    return re.sub("a", "b", input)
```

Comment: [Bubblewrap](https://github.com/containers/bubblewrap) seems like a decent option. You would launch the code as a subprocess wrapped in bubblewrap, which gives you these types of constraints you can add to your sandbox, such as hiding directories, disabling network access, setting cgroups, etc. Within your application managing the subprocess, you could additionally impose constraints such as max runtime.